# When to include interactions in a glm?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, interaction, interpretation

I am using glms to model if the inclusion of a predictor variable is significant in the ability to predict the dependent variable bu comparing residual deviances between the models:

```
Analysis of Deviance Table

Model 1: count ~ variable
Model 2: count ~ origin + variable
  Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df Deviance Pr(>Chi)   
1       524     706.39                        
2       523     699.06  1    7.328 0.006789 **
---
```

However when I include an interaction term between `origin`and `variable` I lose the significance:

```
Analysis of Deviance Table

Model 1: count ~ variable
Model 2: count ~ origin + variable + origin * variable
  Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df Deviance Pr(>Chi)
1       524     706.39                     
2       520     699.05  4   7.3378   0.1191
```

I imagine this is to do with the degrees of freedom. So my question is, how do I make the choice to include the interaction term of not?

The inclusion of the term barely changes the AIC:

```
Including it: 1380.3
Not including it: 1374.3
```

**Edit to add model outputs:**

*Inclusion of the interaction:*

```
Call:
glm(formula = count ~ origin + variable + origin * variable, 
    family = "poisson", data = count_filt_FGT_free)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.6877  -0.6963  -0.3758   0.0306   5.1953  

Coefficients:
                                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                      0.217065   0.110432   1.966   0.0493 *  
originfree                      -0.247836   0.166794  -1.486   0.1373    
variableDuplication              0.136576   0.151107   0.904   0.3661    
variableKnown_target            -1.634130   0.273254  -5.980 2.23e-09 ***
variablePhylogeny                0.125880   0.151485   0.831   0.4060    
originfree:variableDuplication   0.008606   0.227974   0.038   0.9699    
originfree:variableKnown_target  0.040197   0.408914   0.098   0.9217    
originfree:variablePhylogeny     0.005696   0.228629   0.025   0.9801    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 842.35  on 527  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 699.05  on 520  degrees of freedom
AIC: 1380.3
```

*Exclusion of the interaction:*

```
Call:
glm(formula = count ~ origin + variable, family = "poisson", 
    data = count_filt_FGT_free)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.6883  -0.7015  -0.3766   0.0267   5.1789  

Coefficients:
                     Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)           0.21399    0.09162   2.336  0.01950 *  
originfree           -0.24084    0.08929  -2.697  0.00699 ** 
variableDuplication   0.14036    0.11314   1.241  0.21479    
variableKnown_target -1.61631    0.20329  -7.951 1.85e-15 ***
variablePhylogeny     0.12838    0.11346   1.131  0.25784    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 842.35  on 527  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 699.06  on 523  degrees of freedom
AIC: 1374.3
```

Comment: Something that I encounter is if the inclusion of a variable influences the outcome, even if that influence is through an interaction. Consequently, I compare the model that only has one variable (say `origin`) to the model that has both variables and the interaction. Does this sound like what you want to do? (I am a different Dave from the user who posted.)

Comment: @Dave Is that not effectively what I have done? Or are you suggesting drop origin from model 2 also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that `count ~ origin + variable + origin * variable`, does not make sene and will be reduced by the software to `count ~ origin + variable + origin:variable`

The output from the `anova` and AIC both suggest that the interaction term is not needed in your model.

The guiding principle for variable selection should be the underlying theory of the data generating process, not a statistical test based on arbitrary thresholds of p values.

Comment: thank you for this response. Does not including the interaction term reduce my understanding of the model as then I can only see changes in estimates between `origin` at it's reference level and `variable`categories? Where as including it also shown me differences for estimates when `origin`at its other levels for all `variable`levels? I have added some model output to illustrate what I mean.

Comment: My reason for this concern is as when I exclude the interaction we see the inclusion  of origin has some evidence for increasing the predictive ability of the model. With that being the case I want to identify if a `variable` category is driving this.

Comment: There is no evidence for an interaction effect, so the effects you see in the model without interaction are independent of the other variable.

Comment: ah okay that makes sense. Just to clarify. The interaction is showing the estimations for `origin` free against all other `variable` levels and excluding it just shows me estimations for `origin` at reference level and all `variable`levels along with `origin` free against `variable` reference level?

Comment: Does this answer your question ? If so, please consider marking it as the accepted answer, and if not please let us know why.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `origin * variable = origin + variable + origin:variable`. So, perhaps, when you evaluate `count ~ origin + variable + origin * variable` you're checking **2 times the same thing** (`count ~ origin + variable + origin + variable + origin : variable`).

Then, my suggestiong would be to use model 2 as `count ~ origin + variable + origin : variable`.

If this is not a problem (because the code of the analysis of deviance is clever). I would suggest two options:

1. Strictly follow the AIC criteria.
2. Split your data in **training-test samples**, and **check the fit and/or predictions** over the test sample (with some error measurement) for all the models that you want to compare.

Whatever your option is, be sure to be transparent of the method that you'll use.

(P.S. I'm not the same "Dave" that commented the original post. Fun fact :P)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dave. For some reason R wont let me use this format: `count ~ origin + variable + origin : variable` But I think the glm code is clever and notices this.